# Trouble with initializing first project

Tags: python, syntax

I'm a newbie here. I'm trying to print a list out in a doc, and I can't get my python to initialize. It's my first python project, so I'm thinking that I am missing a line of code at the top -- though I cannot figure out what that is. Here is my code:

```
num = input('--')
month = input('--')
crimes = ['_TOT_CLR_MURDER ','_TOT_CLR_MANSLGHTR ','_TOT_CLR_RAPE_TOTAL','_TOT_CLR_FORC_RAPE ','_TOT_CLR_ATMPTD_RAPE ','_TOT_CLR_TOTL_ROBERY ','_TOT_CLR_GUN_ROBBERY ','_TOT_CLR_KNIFE_ROBRY ','_TOT_CLR_OTH_WPN_ROB ','_TOT_CLR_STR_ARM_ROB ','_TOT_CLR_ASSLT_TOTAL ','_TOT_CLR_GUN_ASSAULT ','_TOT_CLR_KNIFE_ASSLT ','_TOT_CLR_OTH_WPN_ASLT ','_TOT_CLR_HND_FT_ASLT ','_TOT_CLR_SIMPLE_ASLT ','_TOT_CLR_BRGLRY_TOTL ','_TOT_CLR_FORC_ENTRY ','_TOT_CLR_ENTR-NO_FRC ','_TOT_CLR_ATT_BURGLRY ','_TOT_CLR_LARCNY_TOTL ','_TOT_CLR_VHC_THFT_TOT ','_TOT_CLR_AUTO_THEFT ','_TOT_CLR_TRCK_BS_THFT ','_TOT_CLR_OTH_VHC_THFT ','_TOT_CLR_ALL_FIELDS ']
f = open('list.txt','w')
for item in crimes:
   f.write(item + num + "-" + num + "\n")
   num++
```

Do you think you could help?

Edit - I made the arguments in open() into strings, and closed the file after writing - unfortunately the file will not run.

Comment: Are you seeing an error?  If so, what? (But, hint, the arguments to `open()` should be strings).

Comment: Also, don't forget to close your file with `f.close()` after writing. And for the `num==` part, you probably want `num += num`...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Among other things, what do you mean by "can't get my python to initialize"?

Comment: If for no other reason, your posted code will fail on the syntax error in the `open` statement: the file name has to be a string.  Put it in quotation marks: `"file.txt"`.

Comment: When you fix the `open` statement note that python doesn't have increment operators so you need `num += 1`